# Gradle android test

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, junit

I have project with next structure:

```
-project_dir
--libmodule
---src[main code path]
---test[test code path]
--app
---src[main code path]
```

I have just one test class with one test function inside inside project_dir/libmodule/test// folder.
I can run it from source file (I am using Android Studio). But if i try to run it using `test` gradle task, it has not found any tests. I have followed modified source configuration (just legacy yet, but seems it does not matter):

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        test {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['test']
            resources.srcDirs = ['test']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['test']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['test']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

    }
```

Have you any ideas why `test` task doesn't see any tests?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an android test, you need to set sourceDirs for configuration `androidTest` instead of `test`, or alternatively, instead of setting each of those srcDirs, you could do:

```
androidTest.setRoot('test')
```